# SQL Using Multiply 3 Times with different ID's

Tags: sql

I have tables called Products and ProductsDetails. I want to get something like the price of an order. So let's say I want 5 pairs of "Headphonesv1" ( Comparing with not ID but name, since name could change ), 2 packs of "GumOrbit" and 7 packs of "crisps". Pair of headphonesv1 costs 10$, gum 1$ and crisps 2$. So the answer that I should get is bill ID, Bill date, and TotalCost which is = 66. My question is how do I make multiple calculations? The code that I've been trying with one at least but I get syntax error:

```
SELECT Products.billID, Products.Date, (ProductsDetails.Price * 5 WHERE ProductsDetails.name LIKE 'Headphonesv1')
FROM Products INNER JOIN ProductsDetails ON Products.billdID = ProductsDetails.billID
```

Also have tried inserting SELECT inside () but then the values that I get are wrong and creating one more inner join inside doesn't seem promising

Comment: can you show an example of what your output should look like?.. are you wanting to see the prices for each item on separate rows or in a crosstab format

Comment: i would want only 1 row to get so that it would print out Total cost of all products that have been ordered

Comment: Honestly, you should store the complete orders in their own table with qty and refrences back to the per-each item cost by ID.  Then, for each order you sum the total cost.

Comment: I know, I'd do that as well but I got a task somewhat similar to this so It's bm but somehow I have to figure it out

Comment: @TesteroniPeperoni I have edited my answer

Comment: @TesteroniPeperoni I have updated my answer once again, let me know if it works now to give you the total cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you just want to see that total cost for multiple items you can use a aggregate and case expression to get the SUM.

```
SELECT  Products.billID,
        Products.Date,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ProductsDetails.name LIKE 'Headphonesv1' THEN ProductsDetails.Price * 5
                 WHEN ProductsDetails.name LIKE 'GumOrbit' THEN ProductsDetails.Price * 2
                 WHEN ProductsDetails.name LIKE 'crisps' THEN ProductsDetails.Price * 7
            END) TotalCost
FROM    Products
        INNER JOIN ProductsDetails ON Products.billdID = ProductsDetails.billID
GROUP BY Products.billID,
        Products.Date
```

this seems very hard coded to serve much use though

Comment: Just curious, first time seeing that sort of `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN ... END` structure. That would work like an `IF ... ELSE IF ... ELSE IF ...` ?

Comment: Going to try this out! Though have to convert it for Microsoft access

Comment: Quick question. What if there are mutlitple prices on same product name? How do I get rid of spaces and other prices? Since I cant use aliases in group by in Access?

Comment: @TesteroniPeperoni  what do you mean by spaces?  you can use a filter like `WHERE ProductsDetails.name IN ('Headphonesv1', 'GumOrbit', 'crisps')` to only get records that have those items.. if you have more than one price then you should probably be using different joins or filter..  Even `INNER JOIN ProductsDetails ON Products.billdID = ProductsDetails.billID` seems like it should be joining on `Products.productID = ProductsDetails.productID` also

Answer (score 0):

Your previous code has a few synax erros. you are closing your parenthesis in the wrong location, and the `FROM ...` clause should be before the `WHERE ...` clause. Change your code to this:

```
SELECT Products.billID, Products.Date, (ProductsDetails.Price * 5) 
FROM Products INNER JOIN ProductsDetails ON Products.billdID = ProductsDetails.billID
WHERE ProductsDetails.name LIKE 'Headphonesv1'
```

and let me know if it works now.

---

**Edited:**

The OP requested how to obtain that information for more than one Product. In that case you could switch the statement to:

```
SELECT SUM(Cost)
FROM (
    SELECT Products.billID, Products.Date, 
        (ProductsDetails.Price * 
            (CASE WHEN ProductsDetails.name='Headphonesv1' THEN 5 ELSE 
                CASE WHEN ProductsDetails.name='GumOrbit' THEN 7 ELSE 0 END 
            END)
        ) AS Cost
    FROM Products INNER JOIN ProductsDetails ON Products.billdID = ProductsDetails.billID
    WHERE (ProductsDetails.name = 'Headphonesv1') OR (ProductsDetails.name = 'GumOrbit')
)
```

And you can continue to add more products.

Comment: It works its all good. but what if i want one more product? Its price is different and I need to calculate it seperately and then add to previous one to get TOTAL

Comment: Also it's worth noting in this case there is no need to use the code `LIKE 'Headphonesv1'` since you can just as well use `= 'Headphonesv1'`. You usually use `LIKE` when you want to find a specific string within a string by doing something like: `LIKE '%Headphones%'`.

Comment: @TesteroniPeperoni I will update my answer, 1 moment.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have another two tables: `cart(cartID int/*,more info*/)` and `cartItems(cartID int /*FK*/, item varchar(50),qty int)` where you add something. Finally,

```
select sum(pd.price * ci.qty) tot
FROM Products p 
INNER JOIN ProductsDetails pd ON p.billdID = pd.billID
inner join cartItems ci on ci.item = pd.name
inner join cart c on c.cartID = ci.cartID
where c.cartID = 123456
```